# Wait for request after evaluate function

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to find a better way to wait for a request after evaluate function

```
//First of all I register the event
page.once('response', async (response) => {
    if (response.url().indexOf('url_for_identifier_request') > -1 && response.request().method() == 'GET') {
      console.log('success')
    }
}

//or
page.once('requestfinished', async (request) => {
    if (request.url().indexOf('url_for_identifier_request') > -1 && request.method() == 'GET') {
      console.log('success')
    }
}

await page.evaluate(() => func())
```

> Note: func() is sync and has another function that makes a request

my question is, use the `response` or `requestfinished`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this is simplest:

```
let responsePromise = page.waitForResponse(response => response.url().match(/foo/))
await page.evaluate(() => func())
await responsePromise
```